# Treemap graph with colored coverage metrics

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to create treemap widget on the sonar dashboard in similar way as on http://nemo.sonarqube.org/
But when I try it then only grey boxes apears there (no colored boxes). 
I see that some projects on http://nemo.sonarqube.org/ are also displayed as gray boxes.

How can I enable the Coverage metric to be properly colored in this graph?

All my projects are in PL/SQL language and I'm using sonarqube 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the PL/SQL plugin does not support test and coverage results, so I'm not surprised that the related metrics are not computed on your project - which in turn explains why the boxes are grey (grey means that the selected metric for the color has no value).

Comment: When I was testing the PL/SQL plugin (on SonarQube 4.2) then this widget works well (each component was properly colored). But now on our production server (SonarQube 4.3) I'm not able to setup this widget again.
The only difference what I see is that on the 4.2 version colors was made according to Rules compliance metric which is not available on SonarQube 4.3. I'm not able to found any other metric which shows the health of components and can be used for Color metric parametr on treemap widget.

Comment: Indeed, RCI has been removed and will be replace by the SQALE rating that we'll introduce very shortly. You can watch the following ticket: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5388

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the information about coverage in some reports, you can use the generic coverage plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Coverage to transform your report in this format and feed your data to the sonarQube platform.